# How to Make 1/5 Column Grid in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout which I need to put three Div beside each other as:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1.5" id="legend"></div>
    <div class="col-md-0.5" id="icon"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"  id="map"></div>
</div>
```

I know it possible to get the legend and icon div inside one `row` but I need to keep them separate while the `legend` will be slide-able and in that case I have to replace the `col-md-10` from `map` with `col-md-11.5`.

Can you lease let me know how I can do this?

Answer (score 11):

## **Bootstrap 3**

Use nesting like this..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
       <div class="col-md-9" id="legend"></div>
       <div class="col-md-3" id="icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" id="map"></div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/125259

**Update for Bootstrap 4**

Here's a 1/5 column in Bootstrap 4 (**no extra CSS or SASS**) using the [auto-layout grid](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-2">2</div>
        <div class="col">1/5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/gjmzB4MTMe

This solution works because Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox. You can get the 5 colums to wrap witin the same `.row` using a clearfix break such as `<div class="col-12"></div>` or `<div class="w-100"></div>` very 5 columns.

Comment: but if  you have a jQuery function to slide left the legend on demand and just keep the icon. so how would you increase the size of the map to cover all remain space?